# how to auto save and close excel file when clicking hyperlink "send"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have this code that will automatically fill the **Subject:** in outlook mail base on the cell value.

```
Range("G5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""mailto:?subject="" & RC[-6] & "" - "" & RC[-1] ,""send"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G5:G1500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

My question is, is it possible in macro, that when the user clicked the hyperlink, excel file will automatically save and close it?

If it is possible, how will I add it on my code?

**Note:** when clicking the hyperlink **Send** outlook mail will pop out.

---

The code was in the **Create New File** when I run the macro it will save a new excel file and all the commands or code written on that macro will apply on the new excel file.

---

here's the whole code of my macro

```
Sub create()
Dim myvalue As Variant

myvalue = InputBox("Input Current Year: 'YYYY'", "Request Registry")
If myvalue = vbNullString Then

Else
    Call req(myvalue)
End If
End Sub
--------------------------------------------
Private Function req(myvalue As Variant)

Dim saveFolder As String

saveFolder = "C:\Document\Macro"

Workbooks.Open "C:\Document\Request.xlsm"
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Visible = False

Cells.Select

Range("A1").Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Contains EW Confidential Information"

Range("B:B, K:K, M:M").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Range("L:L").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0"

Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Requested ID (REQ-" & myvalue & "-###)"
Range("B3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "This portion is to be filled up by requester"
Range("B4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date of Actual Request (Cut-off 3PM)"
Range("C4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Requested by"
Range("D4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Requester's Department"
Range("E4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Engagement"
Range("F4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Nature of Request"
Range("G3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Send Request"
Range("H4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Assigned to"
Range("I4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Status"
Range("J4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Remarks"
Range("K4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date Tagged"
Range("L4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Days Elapsed"
Range("M3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Actual Date Delivered"

Range("G5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=HYPERLINK(""mailto:?subject="" & RC[-6] & "" - "" & RC[-1] ,""send"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G5:G1500"), Type:=xlFillDefault

'Auto save and close code
Dim answer As VBA.VbMsgBoxResult
answer = MsgBox("Job complete?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Pls. Confirm")
If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

rng = "A5:M1500"
Range(rng).Select
With Selection
    .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "REQ-" & myvalue & "-000"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A5:A1500"), Type:=xlFillDefault

ActiveSheet.Name = "Request"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs saveFolder & "\Request.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Add these Code to existing Macro after Auto Fill, will prompt you before Save & Close Workbook.*

```
Dim answer As VBA.VbMsgBoxResult

answer = MsgBox("Job complete?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Pls. Confirm")

If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: Hi this work well but when I try to input a value on a blank cell next to another the message box always pops out. I just want only for column G this code will process. is that possible? right after the requester finished inputting their request on excel file when they click the hyperlink SEND the message box will pops out :) and I forgot that code is on the macro that will create a new file that contains the hyper link :)

Comment: Hi I've edited my question I added my macro and also your code :)

Comment: @gee, could you show me the complete code including mine you have added with, help to test with My sheet or if possible attach file to Drop Box !

Comment: @gee, in fact you have messed up with different jobs,, after Auto fill you have included my code and after that you have another Job and at last one more SAVE & Close Procedure,,!! Do this COPY & Paste DIM line of my Code at top with other Variable. Then  either Remove mine code's from MsgBox to SAVE n Close and use your's since doing the same job,, Or Remove your's SAVE As Close Codes and there only Add mine, in precise YOU ARE USING SAVE & CLOSE at TWO PLACES, where ONLY ONE is required,, at LAST.

Comment: oh! now it worked perfectly!! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @gee,, glad to help you,, keep asking ☺